# Running racket from terminal in OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, racket

In an attempt to set up racket to run from the Terminal, I created a symlink from */Applications/Racket\ v6.2.1/bin/racket* to */usr/local/bin/racket* with the command

```
ln -s "/Applications/Racket\ v6.2.1/bin/racket" /usr/local/bin/racket
```

However, when I try to run *racket* from the Terminal, I get the error *"-bash: racket: command not found"*. I have checked that /usr/local/bin is in my PATH. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
pu@pumbair: ~  echo "/Applications/Racket\ v6.2.1/bin/racket"
/Applications/Racket\ v6.2.1/bin/racket
```

As you see, this leaves the \ sign in the file name which is wrong.

Either quote and don't escape space,

```
pu@pumbair: ~  echo "/Applications/Racket v6.2.1/bin/racket"
/Applications/Racket v6.2.1/bin/racket
```

or escape space and don't quote

```
pu@pumbair: ~  echo /Applications/Racket\ v6.2.1/bin/racket
/Applications/Racket v6.2.1/bin/racket
```

so I'd just

```
ln -sf /Applications/Racket\ v6.2.1/bin/racket /usr/local/bin/racket
```

Comment: Thanks for solving *and* explaining :)